# Scroll to particular item in longlist selector after binding

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, longlistselector

I am using Longlistselector to bind the chat messages. After binding i need to show the last message. But by default it is coming to top message. I tryed scroll to last item "(ScrollTo(lastmessage))" but it is not working. can any one provide the solution.

Comment: Maybe AnimateTo() method will help

Comment: ScrollTo() should work fine, but be aware that it uses the Equals() method inherited from Object, so it will probably do instance comparison over the objects... are you sure that your lastmessage object is trully the same instance that is in the list?

Answer (score 2):

Others have found success by calling UpdateLayout() before ScrollIntoView() on a ListBox.

Comment: This works, I've added it just before the ScrollTo(item) and no more exceptions, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `AnimateTo()` and passing it the last item in the list.

Alternatively, you could interrogate the visual tree of the control and access the ScrollViewer of the internal [Templated]ListBox and call `ScrollToVerticalOffset`.

Comment: AnimateTo() is marked with the ObsoleteAttribute, and on the source code, one can see that all it does is call the ScrollTo() method

Answer (score 0):

Try setting SelectedItemIndex to index of last item.

Comment: The selectedItem isn't automatically brought into view when selected so this won't work.

Comment: I said about Index, not Item. When U change selected index it's scrolling to it. Correctly working with ListBox

Comment: Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                            {
                                ScrollTo(LastItem);
                            }); we need to add a thread to scroll